# Can women use a recorded version of the Salah from a nearby mosque?

Tags: salat, women, jamaat, taraweeh, technology

Most of the Muslim women and a considerable number of old and disabled slaves of Allah cannot leave home or go to the mosque for reasons relevant to them. It is of course rational for them to pray from home and even the Shariah gives the permission. But for **greater sawab (heavenly reward) of Jama'ah** and in the special occasions as that of **Taraweeh** which they cannot perform on their own. **Can these people use an audio-recorded version of the Salah from a nearby mosque?**

Comment: 99.99% percent is way too much. In my city there are special tarawees held only for women. Most of the women living in the vicinity come to pray.

Comment: i agree 99.99 percent is a very large number i would say 70% of women in my town go to taraweeh so in which area would the 99.99% of women be staying at home?

Comment: @NesreenA, Why are we discussing about 99.99% here? It was just a gross number meaning "most of the women". For all of your happiness, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Interesting profitable query. Jazak Allah Khaira dear mate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to be in Jama'h to get the swab of it if you're sick or a woman. It depends mostly based on Intention. Many participate Jamaat but have no sawab because for example they are hypocrite. Also For women the sawab rules are different men and you should first make sure the Hadith you use is equal about both man and woman.

I saw a Hadith for women the nearest position to Allah is when they are at corner of their home.

Also for disabled. Indeed Allah see and know internal intentions. When you have an intention and for any reason cannot do it Allah will give you the sawab.

Also woman has some sawab that men do not have. For example a Hadith says the Jihad of them women is to treat their husband well.